# trigger button with html properties on click in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Awesome evening guys,

I have added a table dynamically using the following jquery code.

```
$(#table tr:last).after('<tr><td class="tbValue"> </td></tr>');
```

After adding it, now I want to access it using the following code

```
$('.tbValue').click(function){
alert('this button is clicked');
});
```

To my surprise its not working. I think the button has an html property however I just cannot seem to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

**As you are creating elements dynamically.**

You need to use  [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

*General Syntax*

```
$(parentStaticConainer).on(event, selector, eventHandler);
```

*Example*

```
$("#table").on('click', '.tbValue', function(){
    alert('this button is clicked')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just enclose the selector in `"` or `'`.

Like this... `$('#table tr:last')`

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/9mgpqmzh/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
$('#table tr:last').after('<tr><td class="tbValue"> B </td></tr>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table'>
  <tr>
    <td class="tbValue">A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```